java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException on Jenkins Agent on every second run
We are having a Jenkins Docker running on a server and on a different machine is a worker running (labeled 'linux'). All of these machines are Linux.
The Worker has the agent.jar of the Jenkins running as the user jenkins which is permanently running as a daemon in systemd.
The pipeline to be executed on the worker first checks out a git-repository, executes some code and persists the results into a database.
After the agent.jar on the worker is started the pipeline runs through with everything green and the results being present. However, when running the same pipeline again I get:
[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential token-jenkins
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://gitlab.intranet.at/gitproject.git
> git init /var/jenkins/workspace/Project/calc_1/model # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.intranet.at/gitproject.git
> git --version
timeout=10
> git --version 'git version 2.39.3'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials token-jenkins
> git fetch --tags--force-progress https://gitlab.intranet.at/gitproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/# timeout=10 
ERROR: Checkout failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
Also:    hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from worker3.intranet.at/1xx.2yy.zz.abc:60478 at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
             at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:199)
             at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1002)
             at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
             at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
             at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke (RemoteGitImpl.java:138)
             at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.execute(Unknown Source)
             at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges (GitSCM.java:1222)
             at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
             at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCHStep.checkout (SCMStep.java:136)
             at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
             at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCHStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
             at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.Synchronous NonBlockingStep Execution.lambda$start$0(Synchronous NonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort (Request.java:346)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate (Channel.java:1083)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed (ChannelApplicationLayer.java:241)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvclosed (ApplicationLayer.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol. Protocol Stack$Ptr.onRecvClosed (ProtocolStack.java:825)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvclosed (FilterLayer.java:289)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed (SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:168)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol. ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed (ProtocolStack.java:825)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed (NetworkLayer.java:155)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$On Ready.run(I0Hub.java:789)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security. ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run (ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0 (ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting

On various occasions this step is done fine, however after the the code is being executed a similar error-message shows up, the execution being ended:
Cannot contact linux: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@4f3519ce:JNLP4-connect connection from worker3.intranet.at/1xx.2yy.zz.abc::42936: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from worker3.intranet.at/1xx.2yy.zz.abc:/1xx.2yy.zz.1ab:42936 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down

After this I restarted the systemd-service of the agent.jar and it worked again. However on the second run it would fail again.
I have tried turning off the firewall-service on the Worker, no changes.
However, what I found to be very strange was that when I let the agent.jar run as root (run directly in the console, not via systemd) I could perform two successful runs.
What could be the reason behind this? My first assumption was there are network issues - a firewall that lets the process do as it pleases for the first time but is suspicious on any further attempt? Could there be an issue that the jenkins-user on the worker doesn't have sufficient rights and something is altered after the successful run?
I haven't found any articles on mapping the agent.jar to any specific port on the worker (this seems to be random), otherwise I'd have that port permanently opened.
The nodes on the Jenkins server are successfully connected and in the Jenkins interface I couldn't find any anomalies. ("Agent successfully connected and online").
I have restarted the Jenkins-Docker as well as the workers several times. No changes.
